# Setting up a windows web hosting in virtual private server

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008, web-hosting, vps

I have 2 virtual private servers which i got from cloudatcost.com with 2 static IPs for one server and 1 static IP for another.
I have installed windows server 2008 R2 on both of them. All I wanted to do is to make one as a webserver and the other as a email and database server and I waanted to use some free control panel to create websites and maintain them. But before doing that I need to setup DNS server and static IP setup which I am not aware of. Someone please help me directing in a correct path of how to setup a server with a domain name and allow it to point as a server for different domains I host in future. I am pretty new to this networking stuff. I am .Net developer please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Server/Hosting configuration is off-topic.

Comment: @MarcB I don't think so, this site has many questions related to many technologies. It is not limited to any programming as far as I know.

Comment: yes, and? registering a domain, buy/leasing a server, blah blah blah have nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[1] First you need to acquire domain for which you will get various registrar.

[2] Domain provider will provide you control panel

[3] Login into Domain control panel and there you need to two step process.Here you need to take help of your Domain provider.

[i] Register Name server of your VPS.Keep IP of VPS, where you will host domain.

```
ns1.abc.com = IP of your VPS
ns2.abc.com = IP of your VPS
```

[ii] Point your domain to VPS

[4]Now you can host your domain on VPS. Global propagation will take almost 24-48 hours time.